# When translating the html template for nulling styles from css to scss , vs code gives an error, tell me how to properly write nulling in scss?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

**css:**

```
* { padding: 0}
```

**scss**

```
 * 
  padding: 0
```

VSCO

**{expected scss(css-lcurlyexpected)}**

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that the curly braces are needed. So, it should look like this:

```js
* {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Files with the extension `.scss` have the same syntax as CSS. If you want it to work without the curly braces and semicolons, you need to change the file extension to `.sass`.